# Selenium/Python - How to click on a button that appears only when cursor is hovering over it?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Basically on the UI there is a button that only becomes visible when hovered upon. I need to be able to click the Delete button when it's visible. Would be ideal if there was some way I can check that I am hovering the right thing by checking against the words Edit Test Contract 1: `uib-tooltip="Edit Test Contract 1">`

Html code:

```
<div class="ibox-content no-margins ">
<span tooltip-class="beacon-uib-tooltip" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="Edit Test Contract 1">
<button class="name btn-link ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" ng-disabled="disableEdit()" mit-mini-modal="" ng-click="editContract(contract)">Test Contract 1</button>
</span>
<span class="icon-container hide-when-dragging">
<div class="show-when-hovering">
<span class="fa fa-times delete-icon ng-isolate-scope" uib-tooltip="Delete" tooltip-append-to-body="true" mit-mini-modal="" ng-click="deleteContract()"></span>
```

The python code I have atm returns nothing for some reason despite me searching for the right css, `ng-click="deleteContract()"`. The method by which I am attempting to click on the delete button is `delete_contract()`. Please let me know if you require any more information, I've tried to be as detailed as possible.

```
class Locator:
    def __init__(self, selenium_context, short_wait_time_sec):
        self.selenium_context = selenium_context
        self.short_wait_time_sec = short_wait_time_sec

def find_elements_css(self, cssSelector):
    return self.selenium_context.find_elements_by_css_selector(cssSelector)

def delete_contract(self, contract_name):
    self.contract_list = self.page_loc.find_elements_css('button[ng-click="deleteContract()"]')
    for contract in self.contract_list:
        if contract.text == contract_name:
            contract.click()
            break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=actionchains#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to simulate hover

```
def delete_contract(self, contract_name):
    action = ActionChains(selenium_context) # create ActionChains object
    contract = page_loc.find_element_by_css_selector('span[ng-click="deleteContract()"]')
    action.move_to_element(contract).perform() # move the mouse to the element
    contract.click()
```

The delete button is in `<span>` tag, not `<button>` tag. The `cssSelctor` should be `'span[ng-click="deleteContract()"]'`

Comment: Only problem with this is that the field `contract_name` is `Test Contract 1` and that `self.contract_list` returns `[]` despite searching for the right code, any ideas as to what your 3rd line of code of your answer might be doing wrong? 
Also do you have any idea how I can get it to check for the correct `contract_name` based on the html code above, should I be searching for a class first?

Comment: @user4659009 I edited my answer. The text `Test Contract 1` belongs to another element and the delete button doesn't have text. You can't compare them.

Comment: that makes sense, I've tried your edited answer, it fails on the 2nd last line of your code with the following error message: `File "/Users/ss/anaconda/envs/web/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 72, in perform
    action()`
  `File "/Users/ss/anaconda/envs/web/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 217, in <lambda>
    self._driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Comment: @user4659009 Try `page_loc.find_element_by_css_selector('span[ng-click="deleteContract()"]')`

Comment: contract returns back the following, not sure if this is helpful in seeing what could be causing the problem or not? - `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c481cda6-ed6e-2949-ae43-7db74c5ea9f6", element="{a251e594-671d-b344-a750-4877b121c554}")>`

Comment: @user4659009 this means `contract` now has the webelement. Ehwt is the new error?

Comment: It fails on `action()` Error as follows:  `File "/Users/ss/anaconda/envs/web/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 217, in <lambda>
    self._driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Comment: @user4659009 It should be `action` without the brackets.

Comment: My bad, that should read `perform()` not `action()`. It's failing on `perform()` in the line `action.move_to_element(contract).perform()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104848/discussion-between-user4659009-and-guy).